# dismissviewcontrolleranimated completion not calling completion on uiimagepickercontroller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, modalviewcontroller

This is the code I have:

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {


    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^(void){
        NSLog(@"Test");

    }];
}
```

It dismisses the modal view controller, but doesn't call the completion argument. Am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

<strike>void completion handlers are filled with a simple `^{`, I've never seen your syntax before....</strike>

```
[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        NSLog(@"Test");

    }];
```

The only possible explanation I can come up with is that your image picker is being dismissed by some other means, and that you are not it's delegate (therefore you would not receive the `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` message).  Another possibility could be a failure within the SDK at the time.  I know from running a quick example project, that the completion block fires as expected in both syntactical models.

Comment: I actually put void in because it wasn't working as you posted above. I changed it back, and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Are you using the right side of the log then?  the farthest right button should be selected.

Comment: This syntax and the syntax in the question are equivalent. Any of `^void (void){ NSLog(@"Test"); }`, `^(void){ NSLog(@"Test"); }`, or `^{ NSLog(@"Test"); }` will become exactly the same Block. IOW, `void` is assumed for a Block's return type and parameter list when nothing is specified.

Comment: Well jeez.  Looking back, I really should delete this... but I can't.  I have no possible explanation for why the completion block wouldn't fire, other than a jankyness with the new API.

Comment: I can confirm that if the view controller you are trying to dismiss in the method has already been dismissed, the completion block does not execute.